# $(document).ready(function() versus $(document).ready(function($)

Tags: jquery

I've been working with Iphone 6 and 6S and found that the first way only work on the 6S while the second way works on both.  (both use IOS 9.2.1)   could someone explain the difference between:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function($)
```

Comment: Both are being executed on the document 'ready' event but the second one is being passed `$` (usually jQuery) as an argument.

Comment: Be interested to see the closure of those. Just looks like your passing a variable in to an anonymous function on the second one.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
 });

$(function($) {
   $("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
 });

Comment: I find it somewhat unlikely that such a difference would cause non-operation on specific iphone models. Are you sure that there aren't other differences at play here?

Comment: yes!  have been testing this for 3 days.  I think something is happening to the namespace

Comment: Both are being executed on the document 'ready' event but the second one is being passed $ (usually jQuery) as an argument  BUT ISN'T THAT REDUNDANT???

Comment: @DCR either you copied wrong in your comment or what you put in post is not representative of the actual code. Comment code is different than the question code. Also lots of people pass the query object as parameters to functions to give them scope.

Comment: the comment code is the closure you asked for

Comment: sorry about that  it should be:   
$(document).ready(function() { $("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"}); }); $(document).ready(function($) { $("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"}); });

Comment: There is in fact a significant difference, the second one encloses the `$` variable, and it's usually used with `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` to make sure there are no conflicts, but it also means that if something is overrwriting the `$` variable in the outer scope at a later time, it's still intact inside the scope, and could mean the difference between working and non-working code, but it also means something is terribly wrong outside the scope of the `document.ready` function, as it shouldn't happen.

Comment: I'm not using js or jquery anywhere else in the document.  The code without passing $ works on the desktop and the iphone 6s bjt not the iphone 6.  Could ssomething still be terribly wrong outside the scope of document.ready or could there just be a problem with the iphone 6.  It does work on the iphone 6 without the $ in chrome but not safari.  with the  $ it works everywhere

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.assert(jQuery == arguments[0] , 'my first param is jquery object')
     console.assert(this == document , 'my this is document')
       
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There is no difference except naming first parameter, try:

```
 $(document).ready(function($) {
     console.log(arguments)
```

and

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(arguments)
 })
```

Javascript does not have method overload based on parameters.

UPDATE: regardless of what definition of anonymous (or named function for that sake) you are passing , jquery will call your function as:

```
  func.apply(document, jquery)
```

See source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/callbacks.js#L80

So your first argument, wether you name it `$` or not going to be jquery object, and your `this` going to be `document`

Comment: everyone says this but it does not work on a Iphone 6 but does work on a Iphone 6S

Comment: most likely it is something else, show your full code that demonstrate that behavior.